# A problem on existence of a continuous surjective map from punctured unit disc to closed unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let D denote the closed unit disc in R^2 . There exists a continuous mapping f : D \ {(0,0)} → {x ∈ |R : |x| ≤ 1} which is onto. I was thinking intuitively that, how we use deformation retraction of an annulus to a circle which is a subset of that , we take that deformation map and then fold the circle to make an closed interval. I think this composition of map will be onto and continuous. But I am not too much sure about that. If anyone check my argument and improve it or give an exact map briefly, I will be grateful to him/her.

Comment: Does D{(0,0)} mean $D\setminus\{(0,0)\}$?

Comment: sorry sir, I will edit this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if it works, yes. But you can just take $f(x,y)=x$ too.